# getting sql to itarate for the row

Tags: php, mysql, loops, echo

im stuck trying to get this line working as I want

```
    echo '<tr><td><div class="'.$row['type'].'">'.$tank_name. '
</div><div class="right">' . array_sum($arr).'</div></td>';
```

apart from trying to use $row['type'] the rest of the script works, in the below code it just echo's the last row value and not each row and I cant figure out where im going wrong

thanks for any help

```
         <?php
                $sql = "SELECT tank_list.name_i18n, 
                       tank_list.tank_id, 
                       tank_list.name, 
                       tank_list.type,
                       tank_list.nation,
                       tank_list.short_name_i18n, 
                       player_list.account_id, 
                       player_list.nickname, 
                       player_list.clan, 
                       garage_list.tank_id IS NOT NULL AS combination_exists 
                FROM   player_list 
                       CROSS JOIN tank_list 
                                  LEFT JOIN garage_list 
                                         ON player_list.account_id = garage_list.account_id 
                                            AND tank_list.tank_id = garage_list.tank_id 
                WHERE tank_list.level = '$tier' 
                       AND player_list.clan = '$clanname' 
                ORDER  BY  FIELD(tank_list.type, 'lighttank', 'mediumTank', 'heavyTank', 
'AT-SPG', 'SPG'), name ASC,  
                          tank_list.name ASC, 
                          tank_list.nation ASC, 
                          player_list.nickname ASC ";

                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                $rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $data = array();
                foreach ($rows as $row)
                {
                    $data[$row['short_name_i18n']][$row['nickname']] =
     ($row['combination_exists'] == 1);
                }

                if(empty($data)){
                    echo "Please select again, no players found matching your search";
                } else {

                                    $firstTank = reset($data);
                                    $players = array_keys($firstTank);
                                    $array = array_keys($firstTank);

                                          $count = count($array);
                                          echo '<tr><th width="170" ></th>';
                                          for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                                               echo  '<th><img src="./img/name/vrt'
    .$array[$i].'.png" title="'.$array[$i].'"></th>';
                                              //echo "<td>".$array[$i] . "\n</td>";

                                          }
                              echo '</tr></thead></div><tbody>';

                            foreach($data as $tank_name=>$arr){

                        echo '<tr><td><div class="'.$row['type'].'">'.$tank_name. '</div><div class="right">' . array_sum($arr).'</div></td>'; // tank name as row label  
                                        foreach($arr as $nickname=>$element){
                                            // output the data for each cell
                                            if ($element == 1){
                                            echo '<td><img src="./img/' . $element . '.png" height="20" width="20" title="'.$nickname . '"></td>';
                                            }else{
                                            echo "<td></td>";
                                            }

                                        }
                        echo '</tr>';
                        // may use this later
                        //echo '<td><div class="right">'. array_sum($arr) .'</div></td></tr>';
                    }

                }
                ?>
```

Comment: `$row` is the last row. Simple example https://eval.in/448669.

Comment: ahh I get it, thanks, but is it possible to get another value (2 really if I can) to be at the same level ?

Comment: I think you should change your logic. You should only have one iteration, I'd think if you have a result from query then there were matches. If there were matches output the matches in that iteration. If not throw that no results message. Also, you shouldn't have variables in your query, you should use prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: thanks for ur help, I got round it in another way using images lol